# How to construct test dependency graph with gradle

Tags: gradle

I work on a large project (several hundred modules, each with tests) and would like to construct a test dependency graph using gradle dependencies.

For example, suppose I have the following modules and dependencies:

```
core <----- thing1 <----- thing1a
     <----- thing2
```

If I run `gradle thing1:dependencies` it will tell me that `thing1` dependsOn `core`.  Instead, I would like to know what modules depend on `thing1` so I can run the tests for thing1 and all dependant modules whenever I change `thing1`.  In the example above, the dependent modules would be `thing1` and `thing1a`

Hopefully there is a simple way to do this in gradle (constructing a test dependency graph seems like a pretty common thing to do), but I have not been able to find anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/abesto/cdcdd38263eacf1cbb51) (which I didn't write) as an inspiration, consider this in the root `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
  task dependencyReport {
    doLast {
      def target = subproject.name
      println "-> ${target}"

      rootProject.childProjects.each { item ->
        def from = item.value
        from.configurations
            .compile
            .dependencies
            .matching { it in ProjectDependency }
            .each { to -> 
              if (to.name == target) {
                println "-> ${from.name}"
              }
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

an example run using a project structure as you describe:

```
$ gradle thing1:dependencyReport
:thing1:dependencyReport
-> thing1
-> thing1a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael!  This isn't working immediately when I dropped it into my project, but I suspect it's because I'm using bndtools to manage my classpath, so I may need to use a different set besides "configurations.compile.dependencies".  I'll play around with it and see if I can get it working with this approach and accept your answer if this has steered me in the right direction